# Fill specific text from other list according to chosen dropdown entry

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have lists of names and initials in separate columns, matched by row:

```
*NAME*                      *Signature*
Alexis Petros                   A. P.
George Kalioris                 G. K.
```

and have created a drop down list of names. I want another cell to display the initials associated with the name chosen in the dropdown.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dropdown is say in A1 based on a list of names say in ColumnL and initials in matching rows in say ColumnM then a formula such as:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,L:M,2,0)
```

should serve.

[image: SO21297227 example]

Comment: That was very useful. I was putting the Vlookup. Thank you for your help!